# Maven excluded jars still included in ear

Tags: maven, jboss

I am building an ear that includes an EJB that contains some axis jars that are causing conflicts with jars that already exist within my JBoss server.  I have two dependencies that have subdependencies on axis. One depends on it directly and the other is a 3rd level transitive dependency.

I am excluding the specific jars I don't want but I still see them in the dependency tree.

This is what the relevant part of the maven-ear-plugin looks like:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
    <configuration>
        <version>6</version>
        <applicationName>${jboss_toolkit_ear_deployment_name}</applicationName>
        <modules>
            <-- modules with transitive dependencies on axis jars -->
            <ejbModule>
                <groupId>com.mycomp.myproject</groupId>
                <artifactId>myejbmodule</artifactId>
            </ejbModule>
            <ejbModule>
                <groupId>com.mycomp.otherproject</groupId>
                <artifactId>otherejbmodule</artifactId>
            </ejbModule>

            <jarModule>
                <groupId>axis</groupId>
                <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
                <excluded>false</excluded>    <!-- required -->
             </jarModule>
            <jarModule>
                <groupId>axis</groupId>
                <artifactId>axis-wsdl4j</artifactId>
                <excluded>true</excluded>
            </jarModule>
            <jarModule>
                <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
                <artifactId>axis-jaxrpc</artifactId>
                <excluded>true</excluded>
            </jarModule>
            <jarModule>
                <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
                <artifactId>axis-saaj</artifactId>
                <excluded>true</excluded>
            </jarModule>
```

And after building this is my dependency tree:

```
[INFO] +- com.mycomp.myproject:myejbmodule:ejb:4.3-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- axis:axis:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.axis:axis-jaxrpc:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.axis:axis-saaj:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |     +- axis:axis-wsdl4j:jar:1.5.1:runtime
[INFO] |     +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |     \- commons-discovery:commons-discovery:jar:0.2:runtime
```

I tried excluding one of the axis jars from one of the dependencies like this

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.mycomp.myproject</groupId>
        <artifactId>myejbmodule</artifactId>
        <version>${myejbmodule-version}</version>
        <type>ejb</type>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
                <artifactId>axis-jaxrpc</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

but when I build I get the following error:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-ear-plugin:2.10:generate-application-xml (default-generate-application-xml) on project someproject-ear: Artifact[jar:org.apache.axis:axis-jaxrpc] is not a dependency of the project. ->

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?